# How to find an integer equivalent of infinity as an index above all others?

Tags: python

I am trying to work a list in Python.  I want to insert new values, but at the extreme end of the list.

`insert()` works OK generally, but it takes two parameters: `insert(0, 10)` adds 10 to the left end of the list, as 0 is lower than (or equal to) the zeroth value in the list. so, if I start with `a=[1,2,3,4,5]`,

```
z=a.insert(0, 10)
```

the new list looks like `[10,1,2,3,4,5]`, which is as expected.

The key question is how to do this and insert at the end of the list.  so, for example,this will work:

```
z = a.insert(100, 20)
```

gives:

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,20]
```

since 100 is larger than the number of items in the list, thus placing it at the end.  But, of course, that will fail to work right if there are more than 100 items in the list.

The logical choice is to define infinity, then use this code to add to the right-end, regardless of array size:

```
z = a.insert(infinity, 30)
```

Since I don't know the array size before starting, I am in a pickle.  I have tried (1) using `math.inf`, as well as (2) using `float("inf")`.  The first fails because "expected an integer but got a float", the second fails similarly.  Trying to 'cast' it - i.e., `top_index = int(float("inf"))` - does not give an integer rep of positive infinity.

I could work around this by saying `a.insert(len(a)+1, 30)`,

...but this seems hokey and requires additional steps (and tolls on speed).

How else can you insert above the highest indexed value?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `a.append(30)`?

Comment: There's no infinity value for integer values in Python, so you'll need to use `append()`. You can also do `z += [42]` to add `42` to the end.

Comment: My avoidance of append is that, over time, I may wish to add both to the left and right ends - as well as in the middle.  It seems much 'cleaner' if there is one function (such as insert) that handles all situations with the right parameters set.  pop() and append() are logically different ; one solution is to define push() as placing something on the right end and pop taking it off (as it does now).  But, it would be much clearer if I had insert(a,b), where 'a' would have a value of infinity, negative infinity, or a concrete value in-between.

Comment: Where would that value of `a` come from so that it is possibly not any concrete integer?

Comment: You can use len() +1 thus you will be sure to have a number bigger than the last index

Comment: @DonKnacki OP already said that in the question. And `len()` alone would suffice.

Comment: @eSurfsnake If you want to insert at either end of the list, you should be using a `collections.deque` instead, which allows for O(1) insertions at either end. `a.insert(0, ...)` is an O(n) operation.

Comment: @chepner Whether that's actually beneficial depends on what else they're doing with the list, though. Surely they're not just building it for fun :-). And their "answer" suggests they do insert in the middle as well.

Comment: len(a)+1 isn't hokey, it's much better than infinity which won't make sense three months from now when you stumble on your code again.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode You can still insert into the middle of a `deque`; it might be slightly slower than inserting into the middle of a `list`, but not asymptotically slower. The key, though, as you mention, is what you want to do with the data structure one it is built. `list.__getitem__` is O(1) for any index; `deque.__getitem__` is O(1) at either end, but slows to O(n) as `i` approaches the middle of the deque.

Comment: @chepner Sure, it's just that you said they should use a deque, using speed as your argument. I just meant that the slower middle insertions might invalidate that argument.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode It's also not all-or-nothing: maybe there's a "build" phase where the majority of the interactions are insertions, followed by a "query" phase, where the majority of the interactions are indexing without modifying the data structure. In that case, it would be worth using a `deque` initially, the converting it to a `list` after most of the modifications are done.

Comment: @chepner Still depends on the kind of insertions. For random insertion positions, deque seems to take [~1.5 times as long](https://tio.run/##dZDPasMwDMbvfgod7RLWdmEwCn2FvcAYw02UTRD/qaMe@vSZFCcrO0wHG0vf75PkfOfvFNvXXOZ5KCkAU0BioJBTYSiY0bNZKl0aR@yYUpy2co/XG9Zq8bGXa@PkRZGN6XEAihMWtt6dDEgMqQBJEsbUTTWl4Z9WHTXwliI6YyKc4eUgYZT5VEaMv9C2q5U6iOadYL@H54dzVUX38Ue1DmUPDZD7T6xpvudlPpq4qTs@xtT/Ubf6M3b04dL707ajkNa5BuItXLCcj@6Xy0Vb76yeDDs4YltnYG21uAonfEWq3M3zDw). For exact middle insertions, ~3 times as long.

Comment: The question is specifically asking about insertions at the ends, and if most of the insertion *are* at one end or the other, using a `deque` is far better (even if there is the occasional middle insertion) than a `list`. If there is a truly even mix of end and middle insertions, you are probably better off just keeping the list unordered and sorting it periodically.

Comment: @chepner *"specifically asking about insertions at the ends"*. That's not true. It's specifically asking about the "right" end. For the "left" end, they already have a solution they're happy with, as they briefly mention to illustrate what they'd like for the right end and then continue to only talk about the right end.

Comment: If it's only the right end, the answer is "use append", which they then rejected because they might also want to insert at the other end.

Comment: For those asking, the core problem I have is this: the code figures out where to place an object into the list based on calculations.  Think of it like this: perhaps we have values and their relative positions AT THE TIME are what we want to do.  For example,  suppose the data points are all calculated (hence, a divide by zero in the calc gives you positive infinity).  One would think this would have been better solved in the insert() function.  Note that if you specify a negative index, it gets placed at that position relative to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on it awhile, I came up with the following code.  It just seems like a lot of overhead; were infinity (positive and negative) allowed, it would be far more compact and elegant.

This code deals with the fact that insert(pos = -2) actually appends that much to the *left* of the current *highest* value; positive and negative infinities can neither be used as an index or have their floor taken.

It's still a bit of overhead, but this code works for all values:

```
def place(pos, value, list):
if pos == math.inf:
    list.insert(len(list)+1, value)
elif pos == -math.inf:
    list.insert(-len(list)-1, value)
elif pos < 0:
    list.insert(-len(list)-1, value)
else:
    list.insert(math.floor(pos), value)


a=[0,1,2,3,4,5]

pos = math.inf
place(pos, 79, a)
print(a)

pos = -math.inf
place(pos, 89, a)
print(a)

pos = 3
place(pos, 99, a)
print(a)

pos = -1
place(pos, 109, a)
print(a)


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 79]
[89, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 79]
[89, 0, 1, 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 79]
[109, 89, 0, 1, 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 79]
```

Proving there are multiple ways to express something in Python (as opposed to the principle of one '"obvious" Pythonic' approach).

Comment: This rather looks like it would be a good part of the *question*.

Comment: And can't you just replace all that with `insert(max(loc, 0), value)`?

Comment: If you're going abstract away which method gets used, switch to a `deque` and use `appendleft` instead of `insert(0, ...)`.

Comment: Still requires making determinations about which function to use.  If insert(position, value) worked with all positive integers, as well as -infinity and infinity, all would work with no overhead.  My goal was to  get away from having multiple functions, but the best I can do, I think, is with my code that hides the determination, and accepts perhaps some string as a parameter that tells you what to do is to have a magic nujmber for left.append for loc.  -1 indicates append to left, 1,000,000 means append to right, any between 0 and the length uses insert as it was designed for.

Comment: Note that in your conditionals here, you are utilizing more O(1) operations than if you just used `len(ls)`. Also, your code is wrong - if you have a list of length 3 (`[1,2,3]`) and you want to append at index 3, your code will return an unmodified list. I really think you're overthinking this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're reaching for, without really knowing it, is a way to package a *value* along with some *metadata* about that value. Buyer beware: this is almost certainly overthinking it for whatever problem you have, but if you're trying to think about it rigorously, this is a way you can do it. Buyer Double Beware: I'm doing this cold from memory, and this is not (currently) tested.

```
IndexType = Enum('Left', 'Middle', 'Right')

class InsertableValue:

    def __init__(self, 
                 value: int, 
                 idx: int = 0, 
                 index_type: IndexType = IndexType.Middle):
         self._value = value
         self._idx = idx
         self._type = index_type

    def insert_to(self, ls: List[int]) -> List[int]:
         match self._type:
             case IndexType.Left:
                 ls.insert(0, self._value)
             case IndexType.Middle:
                 ls.insert(idx, self._value)
             case IndexType.Right:
                 ls.append(self._value)
                 # or
                 # ls.insert(len(ls), self._value)
         return ls
```

This would support something like the following use cases:

```
 >>> ls = [1,2,3]
 >>> x = InsertableValue(0)
 >>> ls = x.insert_to(ls)
 # ls = [0, 1, 2, 3]
 >>> y = InsertableValue(4, index_type = IndexType.Right)
 >>> ls = y.insert_to(ls)
 # ls = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 >>> z = InsertableValue(2, 2)
 >>> ls = z.insert_to(ls)
 # ls = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
 >>> m = InsertableValue(9, 300, IndexType.Left)
 >>> ls = m.insert_to(ls)
 # ls = [9, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
 >>> n = InsertableValue(9, 0, IndexType.Right)
 >>> ls = n.insert_to(ls)
 # ls = [9, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 9]
```

But I don't have a cogent defense of why you'd want to go this far. (And the API can probably be improved, but that's neither here nor there.) It does demonstrate that you can leverage Enums and classes to solve this sort of problem of 'the value needs to carry with it information about how to handle it'. The reason this is *generally* useful is so you're not passing around random numbers (such as the `loc` in your example) that are unclear to future developers (yourself foremost!) with regard to what they mean and what their implication is.

If you're looking to *really* overthink things, there is one improvement that object orientation allows:

```
 class LeftValue(InsertableValue):
     def __init__(self, value: int, idx: int = 0):
         super().__init__(value, idx, IndexType.Left)

 class MiddleValue(InsertableValue):
     def __init__(self, value: int, idx: int = 0):
         super().__init__(value, idx, IndexType.Middle)

 class RightValue(InsertableValue):
     def __init__(self, value: int, idx: int = 0):
         super().__init__(value, idx, IndexType.Right)
```

These extend the original class, so carry the `insert_to` function but provide their own Enum value, so you keep that hidden from anyone using this implementation. I am 95% sure there is a way to put these functions on the Enum itself, but I'd have to do (any) research. It might be worth looking into, though, if you need to handle things like 'Infinite Index' or 'Dollar' versus 'Euro'.

Comment: Oh, I am thinking about it (the idea of a value and a 'number' like infinity saying it goes on the right end of the list).  Precisely what I am doing is make the code 'unaware' of the implementation details, so I don't have to have logic in my main code that passes different parameters (for 'add-to-left' and 'add-to-right'.  Infinity is such a value that is both a signal (there is no number greater).  and comparison works right: so "100 < math.inf" works right since every number is less that math.inf.  Se the code in my own answer (above) and it will be more simple to understand.